# Projectile motion - Initial $y$-velocity to hit $(x,y)$ with given $x$ velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I want a function $f(v_{0x}, x_{end}, y_{end})$ that computes the starting velocity component $v_{0y}$ required to make the projectile land at the specified position $(x,y)$.

$v_{0y}$ is thus the initial velocity in vertical $y$-direction. $v_{0x}$ is the constant speed in positive $x$-direction, i.e. the initial horizontal velocity component. $x_{end}$ and $y_{end}$ are the end coordinates for $x$ and $y$ respectively.

I used the equation $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the angle for the tangent $y_{end}/x_{end}$. This means that $\alpha=\arctan(y_{end}/x_{end})$. Then I can compute the initial velocity $v_{0y}$ by $v_{0y}=\tan(\theta)\cdot v_{0x}$. This is supposed to give the angle for the projectile motion curve with the lowest possible initial velocity according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

To test it out, I compute the $y=v_{0y}\cdot t - g/2\cdot t^2$ as well as $t_{end}=x_{end}/v_{0x}$, but it doesn't reach the correct $y$ at the correct time when I plot it, and it doesn't even reach most positive $y_{end}$ values.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should post your equations, since for example I dont understand "the tangent /."

Comment: @trula The tangent is the ratio between $y$ and $x$ to my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that
$$y(t)=-\frac{gt^2}{2}+\dot y_0t+y_0  $$

and

$$x(t)=\dot x _0 t+x_0 $$

where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the initial position and  $(\dot x_0, \dot y_0)$ is the initial velocity. Plug $x_{end}$ into the second equation to get an expression for $t_{end}$ and plug it back into the equation for $y(t)$. Then, solve for $\dot y_0$.

With all of that said, your solution might be true, as well. I honestly can't comment on it because I don't recognize the equation for $\theta$.
Perhaps you need to use the two-argument arc tangent function? Look up "atan2."

Comment: With your way, I quite easily found the equation $v_{0y}=\frac{y_{end}-y_0}{t_{end}}+\frac{gt_{end}}{2}$ which works. Cheers!

Comment: The equation I was using had a $v_{0x}$ as a free variable. By locking $v_{0x}$, I broke the prerequisites for that equation.